# Communication via Webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

This is really a stupid question.. I really can't figure this out so need help

Basically, our web application will exchange data with another software company web application. That company has already exposed their webservice, and we can perform crud operation via their rest api. If we can full fill our requirement via their rest api, do my software company need to build our own webservice server? In which case do company build their own webservice server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to create a webservice on your side if the other application needs to request and consume data from your application. If you're merely passing data to their API and consuming the response, there should be no need for you to create an API.

Comment: if company A and B have webservice to perform CRUD operation. Both company needs get each other data. In this case only one company has to do all the work and the other company will just relax; right?

Comment: If I am understanding you, then yes you are correct. It's all about the need of an application to request and consume data at will. If both applications need to request data on their own time, then both applications will need an API to handle incoming requests.